# For all real numbers $x$, prove $\lfloor x - 2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor - 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove the following statement:

For all real numbers $x$, $\lfloor x - 2\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor - 2$

I'd appreciate some help with this.

All I know is that the floor function $n$ implies : $n \leq x < n+1$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $n\leq x<n+1$, not $x+1$.  The question you're asking is a direct application of the definition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with? For example: What happens if you write $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \epsilon$ with $0 \le \epsilon < 1$? Then what is $\lfloor x - 2\rfloor$?

Comment: [Related](/questions/348644/number-theory-question-on-the-floor-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be a real number.  Then by the well-ordering principle there exists a unique $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\leq x<n+1$.

This implies that $\lfloor x\rfloor = n$ by definition of the floor function.

---

From here, you need to come up with an argument for why $\lfloor x-2\rfloor = n-2$.

Does it follow from the above that $n-2\leq x-2$?

Does it follow from the above that there is no integer larger than $n-2$, lets call it $m$, such that $n-2<m\leq x-2$?